# How to implement a Kotlin interface that refers to the conforming type?

Tags: generics, kotlin, generic-variance

In the interest of silly thought experiments whose primary purpose is to explore how part of a language works, I decided I wanted to explore a method of making Python programmers more comfortable in Kotlin. Simplistically, I can do this by adding:

```
class Foo {
    private val self:Foo get() = this
    ...
}
```

(Aside Question: Is there a more generalized way to refer to `Foo` as the return type there so that if I changed `Foo` to `Bar`, the variable type of `self` would still refer to the "implementing class of this method"?)

Having to put that line in each class so that we can feel selfishly pythonic is tedious though. So I turned to an Interface. What I initially wanted is something like Swift's `Self` type for Protocols. But I couldn't find anything like that in Kotlin. After reading https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html (which seems to be about Java as much as Kotlin), I concluded that perhaps "Declaration Site Variance" was the thing for me:

```
interface Selfish<out T> {
    val self:T get() = this as T
}

class Foo:Selfish<Foo> {
}
```

This is better. It's undesirable that I have to list the class name twice in the declaration, but I don't think there's a way around that. Is there?

Additionally, this works for final classes, but if I want to have a class hierarchy that conforms to Selfish at the root level, things fall apart:

```
class Foo:Selfish<Foo> { ... }
class Bar:Foo { ... }
```

Methods in Bar that use `self` are of the wrong type. And adding `, Selfish<Bar>` creates a conflict.

Is there a tool I haven't discovered yet to make the type refer to inherited type?

Is there another approach (other than Interfaces) to do something like this?

Did I make the wrong choice using "Declaration Site Variance"?

Comment: I believe you'd need the recurring generic pattern.

Comment: I could pretend I understand what that means @OliverCharlesworth, but I'd only be pretending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

So you can write

```
fun <T>Foo.getSelf(): T {
    return this as T
}
```

Then if you have

```
open class Foo

class Bar: Foo()
```

so

```
Bar().getSelf<Bar>()
```

will return object of `Bar` class

Or even easier, you can write

```
fun <T:Foo>T.getSelf(): T {
    return this as T
}
```

so you can call just

```
Bar().getSelf()
```

to get instance of any class extended from Foo

Answer (score 0):

Per your suggestion @DEADMC, I went with a global extension `val` as opposed to `fun`. It didn't answer the question of how you refer generally to the conforming type in an implementation without using a generic pattern, but it DID solve the bigger issue in a much simpler and scalable way:

```
val <Anything>Anything.self:Anything inline get() = this
```